# NSNumberFormatter Adding Brackets

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, interface-builder, nsnumberformatter

I'm trying to get a NSNumberFormatter to display a currency. I have two UILabels, both are formatted by the same NSNumberFormatter, yet the first one is surrounded by brackets. This is the code I have:

```
    NSNumberFormatter *fmtCurrency = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [fmtCurrency setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [fmtCurrency setGeneratesDecimalNumbers:TRUE];
    [fmtCurrency setCurrencyCode:@"GBP"];
    [fmtCurrency setCurrencySymbol:@"£"];
    // formatter generates decimal numbers
    txtTotal.text = [fmtCurrency stringFromNumber: result.totalBill ]; // displays (£1100.00)
    txtTransition.text = [fmtCurrency stringFromNumber: result.transition]; // displays £120,000.00
```

I've looked around InterfaceBuilder for an "add brackets if too long" option, but there doesn't seem to be one, and the second label which displays correctly without the brackets is longer than the first.

Comment: The total bill doesn't happen to be a negative number does it?

Comment: What are the types for totalbill and transition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trust the system to do the right thing when setting up your formatter, just force the locale you want:

```
NSNumberFormatter *fmtCurrency = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[fmtCurrency setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSLocale* locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_UK"] autorelease]; 
[fmtCurrency setLocale:locale];
```